# Problems when using RyTrack, the GUI-based particle tracking interface written in IDL

Tags: user-interface, idl-programming-language

I am using RyTrack(http://sun.iwu.edu/~gspaldin/rytrack.html) to do particle trakcing, and when I follow the instruction, as below

```
INPUTS: (Once the GUI has been called ...)
1) Image directory: The path to the image sequence files of interest.
   Windows example:  C:/myfolder/*.tif
   UNIX example:     ~/myfolder/*.tif
   (Note: The program can accept tif, jpg, or bmp formats, among others.)

   start: begins a frame-by-frame display. The original image is shown in the 
   top displayand the filtered image in the bottom display.  
   Once started, the image processing
   can be changed on the fly, and the results of these changes will become 
   evident in the bottom image."
```

after i clicked start, nothing happens and IDL said

```
 IDL> rytrack
 Widgets are initialized
 XMANAGER: Caught unexpected error from client application. Message follows...
 Attempt to call undefined procedure/function: 'RYTRACK_EVENT'.
 Execution halted at: XMANAGER_EVLOOP_STANDARD  478 H:\RSI\IDL55\lib\xmanager.pro
                  XMANAGER          708 H:\RSI\IDL55\lib\xmanager.pro
                  RYTRACK           856 E:\Dropbox\Research\Resources\rytrack.pro
```

May I ask how could I fix this and let it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me. Were you running it from the `.sav` file or the `.pro` file?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was running it on.pro.